# What's the use of "production" flag in npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

Some commands like [npm install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) has a `--production` flag, which when used makes npm to install only dependencies listed in `dependencies` and not in `devDependencies` sections of the project manifest.

Here's the description of this flag from documentation:

> With the **--production** flag (or when the **NODE_ENV** environment variable is set to **production**), npm will not install modules listed in **devDependencies**.

**However, what are the practical applications of this flag?**

It can be used only when `npm install` is issued inside of the project directory, probably obtained by cloning a Git repository. Otherwise the package would be installed via `npm install package-name` and it would be automatically installed without `devDependencies`.

Answer (score 1):

Practical example,

on devDependencies you can have https://www.npmjs.com/package/faker which helps you to create fake data to test, which doesnt make sense in production to create fake data.

There are many other packages that you need to have only when you develop, so using flag --production make sense now :).

Answer (score 1):

Use in production where, you don't want to install devDependencies(use only for development).

- `npm install` ---> install  devDependencies +  Dependencies
- `npm install --production` ---> install Dependencies